# Swift global variable

Tags: variables, swift

I'm new in swift.

I would like to figure out how to reuse this variable (item) in other ways:

```
if var item =  currentItem?.listCategoryScheme[countCategoryScheme].listCategory{
              ...
            }
```

I tried to do this:

```
var item:NSObject?
func{
    if item =  currentItem?.listCategoryScheme[countCategoryScheme].listCategory{
                  ...
                }
} func2{
//here reuse item
}
```

but does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variable like:

```
var iteam : NSObject = NSObject()
```

In ViewController class.

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemGlobal:String = String()

func printItem(item: String)
{
    println(item)
    itemGlobal = item
}

func printGlobalItem()
{
    println(itemGlobal)
}

printItem("Swift") //prints "Swift" and assignes the itemGlobal to "Swift"
printGlobalItem() //prints "Swift", from the itemGlobal, previously assigned
```